# Assessing the cluster size for GroupBy calculations

Tags: pandas-groupby, out-of-memory, dask

*Disclaimer first: the results and figures here are by no chance a benchmark for comparing any commercial or non-commercial product.*

Currently my team is using Databricks on Azure for data engineering tasks and as a PoC we decided to give a try to the **Dask** framework. So we created a dedicated k8s cluster of pretty much same size as we use on DBS and deployed Dask there - the total worker RAM is 512 GiB with 84 workers (one worker per CPU) / 8 CPU and 32 GiB RAM for scheduler and try to replicate one of our data flows on a subset of test data.

The flow is the following - from the 3rd party we receive logs on device performance in parquet format. These are standalone files, not like one single `logs.parquet` entity. On our end we receive a csv file with all prq file paths created per month.

Our goal is to read those files into a DataFrame and aggregate them accordingly - by each device on a 1 second rate (raw logs consist of timestamps in nanosecond rate) per device per shift. Essentially these are 3 columns that identify each row in a unique way. And to be more precise each shift per device substitutes for a single prq file mentioned above.

I'm relying heavily on this memory usage report from **Coiled blog**

```
import numpy

def partition_report(ddf):
    series = ddf.memory_usage_per_partition(deep=True).compute()
    total = series.count()
    print(f"Total number of partitions: {total}")
    total_memory = format_bytes(series.sum())
    print(f"Total DataFrame memory: {total_memory}")
    total = total.astype(numpy.float64)
    lt_1kb = series.where(lambda x : x < 1000).count()
    lt_1kb_percentage = '{:.1%}'.format(lt_1kb/total)
    lt_1mb = series.where(lambda x : x < 1000000).count()
    lt_1mb_percentage = '{:.1%}'.format(lt_1mb/total)
    gt_1gb = series.where(lambda x : x > 1000000000).count()
    gt_1gb_percentage = '{:.1%}'.format(gt_1gb/total)
    print(f"Num partitions < 1 KB: {lt_1kb} ({lt_1kb_percentage})")
    print(f"Num partitions < 1 MB: {lt_1mb} ({lt_1mb_percentage})")
    print(f"Num partitions > 1 GB: {gt_1gb} ({gt_1gb_percentage})")
```

[partitioning function](https://coiled.io/blog/dask-memory-usage/)

which after reading the input files says that dataframe consists of 45k partitions and is around 1,3 TiB size with total row number around ***1 763 000 000***. When working on a subset of this data the obvious groupby works just fine, however once I try to process around 1% of data or more - the **KilledWorker** error is constantly appearing. Saturn cloud provides some input on how to leverage split_out and split_every parameters, so I decided to set split_every to the minimum possible value and split_out based on the initial number of partitions. Still this error occurs
[groupBy troubleshooting](https://saturncloud.io/docs/reference/dask_groupby_aggregations/)

```
df = pd.read_parquet( path= full_prq_paths             # a list of input prq files
                    , storage_options=storage_options  # credentials
                    #, gather_statistics=True
                    )

df_1s = df.groupby([df.device_id
                   , df.time_a_date
                   ]
                   ).agg(agg_columns                   # dictionary of columns and agg. functions
                         , split_out = split_amount    # split_amount = df.npartitions // 2
                         , split_every = 2
                         
                        )
```

After some investigation and under assumption that each prq file, i.e. partition, stands for unique shift of a single pump I decided to use map_partitions first to have smaller dataframe prior groupby:

```
df_int_1s = df.map_partitions(lambda part: part.groupby([part.time_a_date
                                                        ])\
                              .agg(agg_columns))
```

This works and partition_report says that intermediate dataframe is 692.21 GiB of size and 936 000 000 rows. However compared to the initial DBS result I'm kinda 1000 rows off ( probably a timestamp within same second occured in several prq files). And reverting to groupby does not help - not enough memory.

```
df_1s = df.groupby([df.description
                   , df.time_a_date
                   ]
                   ).agg(agg_columns
                         , split_out = split_amount
                         , split_every = 2
                         
                        )
```

During all these testing I saw lots of data spill ( yellow and grey colours in the dashboard).

My question is - what might be the next step to cope with this groupby? Is it better to configure cluster with less workers but with more CPUs per worker? Repartitioning the initial dataframe also sometimes result in KilledWorker error. Also none of the prq files is greater than 300Mb size, so not so much of data skew happening. Bluntly increasing the cluster size is like our last resort, but to what extent than we need to increase the RAM?

Answer (score 0):

`.groupby` can be [problematic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QY0zFsaO2j8), assuming the data is distributed across partitions appropriately using `.map_partitions` is the way to go.

> the initial DBS result I'm kinda 1000 rows off ( probably a timestamp within same second occured in several prq files).

This prompts investigation into the data, perhaps there are issues around start/end of a shift (or some other salient time, like midnight).

Comment: Thanks Sultan,

That's a relief, howver what about the computing power? Spark seems to do the same task without breaking the sweat. Using ***rdd.getNumPartitions()*** on the initial dataframe gives around 1900 partitions.

Comment: Hmmm, using `.map_partitions` is very light, it doesn't require much computing power. It scales well, so can make use of a lot of resources for a brief time... I'm not sure what Spark does under the hood, but it seems to use 1900 partitions vs 45K partitions that dask uses (as mentioned in the question). Having a lot of partitions is a problem for tasks that involve data shuffling (like groupby).

Comment: I'm not sure using `map_partitions` with `groupby` will work here, since `map_partitions` is best used when you don't require any communication across partitions (which you need with `groupby` if data are shared across partitions). It sounds like this could be a larger, more detailed discussion appropriate for [Dask discourse](https://dask.discourse.group)!